# run a command and kill if successful

Tags: shell, docker

I have a Rails deployed on Kubernetes. Currently, the application preload time is huge (around a minute) and I'm looking for ways to decrease this time.

One of the solutions I found was a gem called `bootsnap` that caches some important files so everytime you boot up these files are already loaded and the gains in the preload are around 50%

Thing is this will work only if we restart the server and with Kubernetes we always create a new Pod, so there is no cache and there are no benefits in use `bootsnap`.

To create this cache, I only need to run `rails server` so what I thought I could do is maybe add a command in my Dockerfile to start Rails, then, if successful, kill it because, at that point, files were cached already and my image would contain these files

Is there any way I can do something like

```
RUN rails server --daemon
RUN until port 3000 is not up wait
RUN kill server
```

Comment: this is more a shell question than a docker question

Comment: true, added a tag, but can be related to docker as well

Comment: just `lsof -i :3000` will tell if it is open or not, then some bash

Comment: if you do not have lsof, you can do `cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/localhost/3000; echo $?`

Comment: yeah, but I don't really know bash that good, so that is more my question: how

Answer (score 2):

I think it worked with

```
#!/bin/sh

bundle exec rails server --daemon

while ! nc -z localhost 3000; do
  echo "Checking for Rails"
  sleep 0.5
done

kill $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)
```

Comment: what's your approach to put this in a container?

Comment: these commands are in a file called `cache-warmup.sh` and then `RUN DATABASE_ADAPTER=nulldb ./cache-warmup.sh`